# How to run a method in a different class file in java

Tags: java, class

So I have two files, gradebook which stores my main and some other methods and then FSCstudent which has my student class and some other things. I want to get an integer value from a getter.

```
public static void searchByID(int idSearch) {
    numStudents = FSCstudent.getNumStudents();
}
```

So this is my attempt at trying to get the int value from this:

```
public int getNumStudents() {
    return numStudents;
}
```

However, I just keep getting the error nonstatic method getNumStudents() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: The error means that the `getNumStudents()` method should be static. Static means that a program can access the variable/method without creating an instance of the class, for example `new FSCstudent().getNumStudents()` is not static as you are creating an instance of `FSCstudent`, while `FSCstudent.getNumStudents()` is static because you are accessing it directly without first creating an instance of `FSCstudent`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this:

```
public static int getNumStudents() {
    return numStudents;
}
```

Be careful though because you need to set `numStudents` to static too. Like this:

```
private static int numStudents;
```

The reason being your main function is a static function and a static function can't access non-static methods. If you don't know what a static method is read this: [Static function in Java](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java).

**Edit:**
As @Jason also pointed out, if you are trying to create a list of that `FSCstudent` class, you need to create an object first. The code (directly from Jason):

```
FSCStudent student = new FSCStudent();

int students = student.getNumStudents();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so like @GauravMall stated you can reference the function statically by adding the static modifier to the method. Another option would be to create an instance of `FSCStudent` and call the method in a non-static fashion.

**Static Version:**

You will have to make the member `numStudents` static as well by using the static modifier.

```java
private static int numStudents;

public static int getNumStudents() {
    return numStudents;
}
```

**Non-Static Version:**

```java
FSCStudent student = new FSCStudent();

int students = student.getNumStudents();
```

Comment: Right this is actually better! Forgot to put that.

Comment: I mean, to each their own, your way is perfectly valid in certain scenarios!

Comment: Exactly, it depends on the OP's implementation, but still, it's important to have both in your answer :)

Comment: You're a saint.